# Get Base Directory of one project from another project's class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two asp.net projects in one solution. One is WebForms and the another is a WebApi project.

I am trying to save an image in the root folder of the WebForms  using a method in the WebApi. Unfortunately, I am unable to get the `BaseDirectory` of the WebForms from the WebApi method.

This is what I have tried:

```
//this returns me only the root folder of the API i.e; D:\Projects\MyApp\API\)
string basePath = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
```

Is it possible to do what I am trying?

Comment: Why the WebApi tries to save in a WebForms project path? Why not expose an API method from WebForms to save the file? 
Alternatively, couldn't they both share some common folder to save the required files?

Comment: The project's initial structure was to maintain two seperate projects for API methods and Forms. may be a bad design. But I cannot change that now

Comment: I'd look at a `web.config` [app setting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa903313(v=vs.71).aspx) in the API where the value is the directory of the WebForms application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can navigate to you related app if it destination meet some folder tree position requirement using this:

```
string relativePath = "..\\Web\\";
string basePath = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
string webPath = Path.GetFullPath(baseDirectory + relativePath);
```

Comment: It is not sure where the related app will be hosted, Otherwise this might be a solution.The only relation between them is the API methods are called from the related webapp.

Comment: Also the root folder of both the projects could be changed by the deployment team. So i cannot rely on this solution